# Come to the Overlook Hotel (Writers.SE chat)

Tags: discussion, chat

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel

Also, consider this a solicitation for any ideas as to what interesting things we could do with chat rooms.  Perhaps we could try some round-robin short-form writing, some sort of shared-world project, or even critiques.  Since chat is a little more easygoing, it might be a good place to play around with stuff that doesn't really fit on the Q&A site.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to overlook, the Overlook Hotel. It's empty and a little bit creepy.

I'd love to see chat rooms used for brainstorming, prompts, sharing short bits of work. Although I have to wonder, do the same licensing issues apply to creative work in chat rooms? I assume so, since it's archived and available.

Perhaps we could have hosted topics and guests at specific times.

Comment: Look at me, saying "we". That's one of the more amazing things about the stackexchange model, how quickly community develops.

Comment: Hosting events on chat is a good idea. I've been a little sad about our empty chat for a while, but I haven't really come up with any good ideas to rectify the situation.